# .NET CTP5 Code First EF. LazyLoading set to False still doesn't cause explicit loading of one to one

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, code-first, one-to-one, entity-framework-5

I have the following (vb.net) model classes:

```
Public Class Contact
    Implements IModelEntity

    Public Property ID() As Integer

    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Overridable Property ContactDetails() As ContactDetails

    Public Sub New()
        ID = 0
        Name = ""
        ContactDetails = New ContactDetails
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Person
    Inherits Contact
    Implements IModelEntity

    Public Property Surname() As String
    Public Property DOB() As DateTime

    Public Sub New()
        Surname = ""
        DOB = DateTime.Today
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class ContactDetails
    Implements IModelEntity

    Public Property ID() As Integer

    Public Property WebAddresses() As List(Of WebAddress)
    Public Property PhoneNumbers() As List(Of PhoneNumber)
    Public Property EmailAddresses() As List(Of String)
    Public Property SocialMediaAliases() As List(Of SocialMediaAlias)
    Public Property PostalAddresses() As List(Of PostalAddress)

    Public Sub New()
        ID = 0
        WebAddresses = New List(Of WebAddress)
        PhoneNumbers = New List(Of PhoneNumber)
        EmailAddresses = New List(Of String)
        SocialMediaAliases = New List(Of SocialMediaAlias)
        PostalAddresses = New List(Of PostalAddress)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class eCRMContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = False
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder)
        MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)

        modelBuilder.Entity(Of Contact).HasRequired(Function(x) x.ContactDetails).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete()
    End Sub

    Public Property ContactDetailsSet As DbSet(Of ContactDetails)
    Public Property Persons As DbSet(Of Person)
End Class
```

In the person controller, I have the following:

```
    ' GET: /Person/Edit/5

    Function Edit(id As Integer) As ViewResult
        Dim person As Person = db.Persons.Find(id)

        Return View(person)
    End Function
```

However, even with LazyLoading set to False, person.ContactDetails is not loaded! I've checked the database and the relationships have been generated correctly and the keys that code first generated have the correct values. What's going on?

**Update**

I've also tried explicitly doing:

```
db.Persons.Where(Function(x) x.ID=id).Include("ContactDetails").SingleOrDefault()
```

and also

```
db.Persons.Where(Function(x) x.ID=id).Include(Function(y) y.ContactDetails).SingleOrDefault()
```

but it still didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Setting lazy loading to false doesn't turn on automatic eager loading - it just turn off lazy loading. If you want to load relation you must use `Include` method for that in your query (and you must use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Find`).

Comment: Tried `code`db.Persons.Where(Function(x) x.ID=id).Include("ContactDetails").SingleOrDefault()`code` and it didn't work.

Comment: It could be [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/544639/ef4-inheritance-defined-using-queryview-doesnt-work-properly-with-association)